# Select in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

Is there any use in using the select() function ?

From my (small) experience I tend to believe that threads are enough.

So I wonder, is select() just a didactic tool for people who don't yet know threads ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example. You have a moderately busy web server with something like 100K connections. You're not using `select` or anything like it so you have one thread per connection, implying 100K threads which quickly becomes a problem.

Even if you tweak your system until it allows such a monstrosity, most of the threads will just wait on a socket. Wouldn't it be better if there was a mechanism to **notify you when a socket becomes interesting** ?

Put another way, threading and `select`-like mechanisms are complementary. You just can't use `threads` to replace the simple thing `select` does: monitoring file descriptors.

Comment: Ok. I understand what are you saying. Can you provide a best practice in using threads and select for a client-server architecture ?

Comment: @coredump It depends on what you're doing really.

Comment: It is a file transfer project . The server hosts data about the clients. The actual transfer is peer-to-peer between the clients. The server only holds what files and other data of the hosts. The clients can accept multiple connections, and I want to transfer part of the file then go to another connection, transfer part of the file and so on.

Comment: @coredump Consider the number of descriptors you would be using, the time threads would be waiting blocked etc. You can even use a hybrid scheme, where a `select` loop pushes tasks in a thread pool.

Comment: @cnicutarYes now that I understand that I can use both of them, I think that is the best solution. Thank you.

Comment: A single select call essentially monitors for a single type of event. For e.g. if you have a chatting app, where you can't predict when would you call receive() when some one sent you a message Or call send() when you entered data on screen. This kind of activity can only be achieved with two separate threads or similar mechanism. Moreover, for a high performance server setup, a mix of both is used i.e. there is a pool of processing threads (much less than the actual number of connections) which pool clients among them based upon who is free.

Answer (score 1):

Single-threaded polling is by far simpler to use, implement and (most importantly) *understand*. Concurrent programming adds a huge intellectual cost to your project: Synchronising data is tricky and error-prone, locking introduces many opportunities for bugs, lock-free data structures cause performance hits, and the program flow becomes hard to visualize mentally (or "serialize" perhaps).

By contrast, single-threaded polling (maybe with `epoll`/`kqueue` rather than `select`) gives you generally very good performance (depending of course on what exactly you're doing in response to data) while remaining straight-forward.

In Linux in particular, you can have timerfds, eventfds, signalfds and inotify-fds, as well as nested epoll-fds, all sitting together in your polling set, giving you an very uniform way of dealing with all sorts of "asynchronous" events. If eventually you need more performance, you have a single point of parallelism by running several pollers concurrently, and much of the data synchronisation is done *for you* by the kernel, which promises that only one single thread receives a successful poll in the event of readiness.